# Dijkstra algorithm under constraint

Tags: graph-algorithm, shortest-path, dijkstra

I have N vertices one being the source. I would like to find the shortest path that connects **all** the vertices together (so a N-steps path) with the constraint that all the vertices cannot be visited at whichever step.

A network is defined by N the number of vertices, the source, the cost to travel between each pair of vertices and, for each step the list of vertices that can be visited

For example, if N=5 and the vertices are 1(the source),2,3,4 and 5, the list [[2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]] means that for step 2 only vertices 2,3 and 4 can be visited and so forth...

I can't figure out how to adapt the Dijkstra algorithm to my problem. I would really like some ideas Or maybe a better solution is to find something else, are there others algorithm that can handle this problem ?

Note : I posted the same question at math.stackexchange, I apologize if it is considered as a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any adaptation. Dijkstra algorithm will work fine under these constraints.

Following your example:
Starting from the vertex 1 we can get to 2 (let's suppose distance d = 2), 3 (d = 7) and 4 (d = 11) - current values of distance is [0, 2, 7, 11, N/A]

Next, pick the vertex with the shortest distance (vertex 2) - we can get from it to 2 again (shouldn't be counted), 3 (d = 3), 4 (d = 4) or 5 (d = 9). We see, that we can get to the vertex 3 with distance 2 + 3 = 5 < 7, which is shorter than 7, so update the value. The same is for the vertex 4  (2 + 4 = 6 < 11) - current values are [0, 2, 5, 6, 9]

Mark all the vertices we visited and follow the algorithm until all the vertices are selected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but there is something I don't understand. In my case a path has to contain every single vertice, I don't see why Dijkstra would do that

Comment: @Jkev if all the vertices should be in the path, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem - Dijkstra won't work here